# How do I uniquely match an outlook sent email to its corresponding outlook draft (MAPI MailItem)

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I'm trying to match an outlook "draft" with its corresponding outlook "sent email" after the draft is sent, but it doesn't seem like I'm getting anywhere.

I've tried using the `ConversationId` and this almost worked. A draft can be matched to a sent email through the `ConversationId`, but the problem is that a user can create 2 different drafts and thus break this logic (as the 2 drafts will have the same `ConversationId` and thus cannot be uniquely identified to the sent email.

I've tried using the `EntryId` property, but of course, it's different on the draft than on the sent email. I've tried seeing if the `parent EntryId` to see if anything could be filtered out, but that didn't worth either.

I've dug deeper into the MAPI and found `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W` but that doesn't exist on the draft.

In essence (sorry for the rambling), my question is how do I uniquely identify an outlook draft to its associated sent email (after the draft is sent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PR_SEARCH_KEY` - but it can change (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2009/12/14/pr_search_key-and-draft-messages/). `PR_RECORD_KEY` as well as `PR_ENTRYID` are changed when copied.

Why not set your own named property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`? Just don't use `MailItem.UserProperties` as that can cause the message to be sent in the TNEF format.

Comment: Own named properties is working! But I have 1 more small followup question (I picked up this project half way through). Following the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/propertyaccessor-setproperties-method-outlook I'm setting the properties like this `item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}/TestProperty", "TestValue");` What do the hex digits in that schema means?

Comment: Your own GUID. Look at the messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button). Also see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/utils.htm#named-props